# ReactJS: change route based on click event

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am looking for a way to change routes in reactJS using `react-router` when a user clicks a button.

Here is the relevant code (details of components have been omitted for brevity) from my `jsx` file:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var {Route, Router, IndexRoute, hashHistory, browserHistory} = require('react-router');
var {Link, IndexLink} = require('react-router');

var Main = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <div>
                <header>
                    <Router history={hashHistory}>
                        <Route path='/' component={Splash}></Route>
                        <Route path='login' component={Login}/>
                    </Router>
                </header>
                <footer>
                     <Button_/>
                 </footer>
             </div>
         );
     }
});

var Login = React.createClass({
     render: function(){

         return(
             <div>This is the login component</div>
         );
     }
 });

var Button_ = React.createClass({

    handleClick: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    },

    render: function(){
        return(
            <Link to='/login' activeClassName='active'>LOGIN</Link>
        );
    }
});

var Splash = React.createClass({

    render: function(){

         return(
             <div>This is the Splash component</div>
        );
    }

 });

 ReactDOM.render(<Main/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

As you can probably see by now, the `Splash` component is the default one shown on the page. When the user clicks the `Link` in the `Button_` component, I want the `Splash` component to be replaced with the `Login` component in the DOM.

I'm running a python server to test, so the URL looks like `http://localhost:8000/public/#/?_k=hqkhl0`

The code I have currently doesn't do what I want it to do. If I manually type in `http://localhost:8000/public/#/login`, the page changes, but clicking the button doesn't work.

I also tried manually changing the page by using `browserHistory.push()` within the 'handleClick' function of 'Button_' (and also added the `onClick` property in the correct place), however this didn't give me the results I wanted.

I first tried

```
browserHistory.push('/#/login');
```

This resulted in a redirect to `http://localhost:8000/#/login`, obviously not right.

I then tried

```
browserHistory.push('public/#/login');
```

which resulted in a redirect to `http://localhost:8000/public/public/#/login`, again, incorrect.

How can I successful route to the `Login` component?

Comment: sounds like you need to configure your python server to route all requests to --> index.html(were your react app is) so react-router can handle all the routing....

Comment: @deowk the python server is pointing to the folder where index.html resides, however the routing is still not working.

Comment: So are you routing all requests to index.html for example if I was using express I would dow something like this --> ```app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './index.html'));
});```

Answer (score 1):

In your handleClick function just try this:

```
this.props.router.replace('login')
```

this is with "react-router": "^3.0.2",

Answer (score 1):

```
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'
const history=useHistory()
handleClick=()={
history.push('/path')
}
```

RRD provide us useHistory hook with help of which we can access history object of our browser and history.push('/path') method push  the browser url  to the url we passed it inside barckets.

Answer (score 0):

You could try implementing the login route as a child route of the splash route, which could mitigate the problem of going to the wrong level, so to speak.

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
  <Route path='/' component={Splash}>
    <Route path='/login' component={Login}/>
  </Route>
</Router>
```